# Iterate over individual pixels of a UIImage with height information

Tags: ios, image, image-processing, uikit

I'm trying to automatically crop an image that has extraneous white color above and below it. I'm trying to iterate over the pixels of the image to find the first non-white pixel to set that as the appropriate height to crop from the top, and then using the last non-white pixel as the appropriate height to crop from the bottom.

I've attempted using `CGBitmapContextGetData` to generate the individual pixels but as far as I can tell this only preserves the RGB color of the pictures so the information of the pixel height's is lost.

Does anyone know any ways of iterating over individual pixels of a UIImage while being able to access the height information of those pictures? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can grab the pixels from the cgImage representation of the UIImage.  The width and height are found on the size field of the UIImage.  For each pixel, check the RGBA values for that pixel.  If they aren't all 255 then its a non white pixel.

```
    func firstNonWhitePixel(image: UIImage) -> CGPoint? {
        let width = Int(image.size.width)
        let height = Int(image.size.height)
        if let cfData = image.cgImage?.dataProvider?.data, let pointer = CFDataGetBytePtr(cfData) {
            for x in 0..<width {
                for y in 0..<height {
                    let pixelAddress = x * 4 + y * width * 4
                    if pointer.advanced(by: pixelAddress).pointee != UInt8.max ||     //Red
                       pointer.advanced(by: pixelAddress + 1).pointee != UInt8.max || //Green
                       pointer.advanced(by: pixelAddress + 2).pointee != UInt8.max || //Blue
                       pointer.advanced(by: pixelAddress + 3).pointee != UInt8.max  {  //Alpha
                        return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
```

Comment: Reading this code, and indeed trying it out, I'm not sure this is correct.

pointer.advance(by: pixelAddress) implies this is going to skip over a BUNCH of pixels, and it's advancing it, it's not saying "pointee at pixelAddress"...

Comment: thats exactly what its supposed to do: keep skipping pixels as long as they are white.  If its not working for you its either because your target pixel is a different color from RGBA(255,255,255,255) or because your image is not a 32 bit RGBA image.  in either case I would create a new question with a sample image that exhibits this problem; otherwise its difficult to tell what's wrong in your case.

Comment: Just read the code.  Advanced by... you're making giant leaps forward because you are advancing the pointer not by 1.  if the method were pointer[pixelAddress], this would likely be correct.

Or you could blame the user...

Comment: I don't think you understand how the swift api naming conventions work.  A gerund or past participle such as `advanced` indicates a copy and not a mutation.  So `pointer.advanced(by: pixelAddress + 2).pointee` is the equivalent to c++ `*(pointer +pixelAddress + 2)` which is the same as `pointer[pixelAddress + 2]`. See the apple docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafepointer/3393173-advanced

Comment: OK, yes you're right about the semantics of method names.  I solved it differently now since this code didn't work for me.  Perhaps my image wasn't RGBA, but I'm fairly sure it was when I tried this solution.  Anyway, thanks for replying.

Comment: @horseshoe7 Can you share with us the solution here? I'm trying to achieve the same as you did, but not just from top and bottom, but also from left and right side. And my background is not white also. Any advice?